# Determine the limit of a sequence using squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

$$  \left(\frac{\left(1+2\left(-1\right)^x\left(x+4x^2\right)\right)}
    {5+7x^3}\right)\left(\sin \left(\frac{\left(3x\pi \right)}{7}\right)\ +\cos 
    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)
$$
I have to find the limit of this equation. I am confused by the (-1)^x and how to factor that out. Thanks for the help

Comment: Limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$? And $x$ is an integer?

Comment: Since the title mentions a sequence it is preferable to use symbol $n$ instead of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might observe that :

$$\frac{1-2(n+4n^2)}{5+7n^3} \leq \frac{1+2(-1)^n (n+4n^2)}{5+7n^3} \leq \frac{1+2(n+4n^2)}{5+7n^3} $$

Of course, you still have to deal with the trig terms, but they ought to be fairly easy to bound.

Answer (score 1):

Noting
$$  \bigg|\left(\frac{\left(1+2\left(-1\right)^x\left(x+4x^2\right)\right)}
    {5+7x^3}\right)\left(\sin \left(\frac{\left(3x\pi \right)}{7}\right)\ +\cos 
    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\bigg|\le\frac{2\left(1+2\left(x+4x^2\right)\right)}
    {5+7x^3}
$$
and 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2\left(1+2\left(x+4x^2\right)\right)}
    {5+7x^3}=0$$
one has
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\left(1+2\left(-1\right)^x\left(x+4x^2\right)\right)}
    {5+7x^3}\right)\left(\sin \left(\frac{\left(3x\pi \right)}{7}\right)\ +\cos 
    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=0. $$